# Где хранятся детали кредитных карт пользователей WooCommerce Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, безопасность, woocommerce, ssl, paypal

Здравствуйте! 
Чтобы повысить безопасность своего сайта, или по крайней мере не сделать её хуже, хочу понять где хранятся данные/детали кредитных карт моих клиентов у WooCommerce.

На сайте использую такие платежные системы как PayPal, Stripe.

> У меня на сайте "товаром" являться планы: standart, base, pro и там
>   снимается месячная оплата в определенном размере. как WooCommerce
>   может запрашивать платеж с определенной карты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нигде. WooCommerce соединяется с платежным сервисом типа PayPal, который ведет всю обработку. В том числе, может хранить данные кредитных карт.

Comment: У  меня на сайте "товаром" являться планы: standart, base, pro и там снимается месячная оплата в определенном размере. как WooCommerce может запрашивать платеж с определенной карты, если вы говорите что это просто шлюз?

Comment: @АртемГолинка, Вам всё верно говорят. ВП просто передаёт клиента посреднику (биллинг-системе), но не данные его карт.

Comment: Я не знаю, какой у вас плагин продает "планы". Но я писал шлюзы. Из платежного шлюза WooCommerce в банк отправляются данные о товаре, цене и покупателе (никаких карт). Сервер банка спрашивает карту, проводит оплату и возвращает моему шлюзу результат: да, нет, подробности.

Comment: @SeVlad где бы взять такой плагин, чтобы продавал "план" позабористее?